# Ubuntu 19 second screen flicker in portrait mode only (dual monitor)

Tags: multiple-monitors, 19.04

I have a screen flicker issue with Ubuntu 19 + Intel UHD 620 + second 28" 4k monitor.

Interestingly enough - the screen flickering ONLY happens when the second monitor is in the portrait mode.  Landscape mode works perfectly.  Any ideas on what I can try to fix this?

I ran all the possible system updates - and the system does seem to be up to date.

### some outputs of commands that other posters seem to include:

```
z@z:~$ lspci | egrep ' VGA|3D' 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

### 2

```
z@z:~$  glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.3.0-devel (git-a1ff8db 2019-09-26 disco-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.3.0-devel (git-a1ff8db 2019-09-26 disco-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.3.0-devel (git-a1ff8db 2019-09-26 disco-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

p.s. set up : acer swift 3 v i7 + 32gb ram (should be ok for graphics) + ssd (fast os)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by following the [directions in this blog post](https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/screen-tearing-on-intel-graphics.html)

In summary, you create a file, restart the computer, and everything works magically:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

add in the following text to the file, save reboot:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

best of luck.